# Import csv to rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I would like to add cvs data to my RoR app. I have tried to follow the following tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel

In the front-end it looks like it works (I am able to add a file), however it get the following error when clicking on the import button:

```
 invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

My pins controller looks like this:

```
.... 

 def import
  Pin.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Restaurants imported."
  end
....
```

According to the tutorial I have modified my pin model to this:

```
....
 def self.import(file)
        CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        Pin.create! row.to_hash
     end
    end
 ....
```

I have also added a form_tag to my view to add the csv file.Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @mudasobwa that won't work because import is defined as a class method.

Comment: Ah, yeah, sorry, I did not notice that `Pin` is your model.

Comment: So any thought on a solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have edited the blog post with some new modifcations. I now receive the following error:  invalid byte sequence in UTF-8. Does anyone knows what to do?